# MySQL insert trigger with multiple inserts at the same time

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I'm trying to generate a primary key for my table, something like this
(simplified version) - the purpose is to have a daily incremented key:

```
DELIMITER ^

CREATE TABLE `ADDRESS` (
    ID INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT -1,
    NAME VARCHAR(25),
    PRIMARY KEY(`ID`))^

CREATE FUNCTION `GETID`()
RETURNS INTEGER
deterministic
BEGIN
    declare CURR_DATE DATE;
    declare maxid, _year, _month, _day, newid INTEGER;

    set CURR_DATE = CURRENT_DATE;
    set _year = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM CURR_DATE);
    set _mon = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM CURR_DATE);
    set _day = EXTRACT(DAY FROM CURR_DATE);
    set newid = (_year - (_year/100) * 100) * 10000 + _mon * 100 + _day;

    select max(ID) into maxid From `ADDRESS`;
    if (maxid is null) then
        set maxid = 0;
    end if;

    if (MAXID / 1000 != newid) then
        set MAXID = newid * 1000;
    end if;
    set MAXID = MAXID + 1;
    return MAXID;
END^

CREATE TRIGGER `ADDRESS_ID_TRIGGER` BEFORE INSERT ON `ADDRESS`
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    if new.id=-1 then
        set new.id = getid();
    end if ;
END^

COMMIT^

DELIMITER ;
```

Generally it works fine, but when I test it with multiple inserts at the same time
it obviously fails (e.g. no dirty reads, the select max will fail for the 2nd insert,
thus it will generate the same id as fro the 1st insert).

Comment: Why do not you use AUTO_INCREMENT? What actually do you want?

Comment: To have the key "restart" daily, as you can see from the code, the primary key's format is "strictly formatted", e.g. the first digits are YYMMDD and then you have a max 1000 per day element, e.g. the full format for the key is YYMMDDCCC. So it is not an autoincrement key at all.
Please note that YES I know this lame, etc. what-if-more-than-1000-elements-per-day, etc., but this is a requirement let it lame be, I have to live with it.

Comment: Do you want to know when row was added/edited?

Comment: Not quite, don't use that information about changes/new records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround:

1. Make primary key AUTO_INCREMENT.
2. Add TIMESTAMP field and use BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE trigget to set CURRENT_TIMESTAMP().

Also you can use `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` option for TIMESTAMP field, value will be updated automatically.

So, ID is ID, and TIMESTAMP field contains date and time.

Comment: Will the autoincrement primary key be already stored in 'new' when I get to the 'before insert'? If yes, then a second question. Can I change a autoincrement field's value in the trigger? I'm thinking about "only" do the daily reset (e.g. to change the key value to the YYMMDD when the date change is detected) in the trigger otherwise it would behave as a "normal" autoincrement variable. Is it feasible?

Comment: Ok actually i'll do Devart suggested, that is easiest